# Homology Question about Kunneth Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

I can't find a statement of the Kunneth Theorem involving $H_i(X).$  The one on wikapedia uses $H_i(X; F)$ where $F$ is some field.  I am not sure what that means.  I just want to know what it means in the standard sense.  Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: what Künneth theorem do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to say something similar to what is one wikapedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem

Comment: The one under Singular homology with coefficients in a field

Comment: I am looking for a toll that would let me find the homology of say the cross product of a sphere and a Klein Bottle.

Answer (score 2):

You want the theorem in the wikipedia page which is at "singular homology with coefficients in a PID"; in your case $R=\mathbb Z$.

If for example one of $X$ and $Y$ has *free* homology groups (say, finitely generated with no torsion), then the term involving the Tor is zero, and you get the isomorphism you want, namely $$\bigoplus_{i + j = k} H_i(X) \otimes_R H_j(Y) \cong H_k(X \times Y).$$ This applies to $S^n\times X$ for all $X$ and all $n$, for example.

Otherwise, you need to learn about $Tor$, which is not that bad, really!

Comment: But, probably, to compute the homology of $S^2\times K$, with $K$ a klein bottle, you should really use the Mayer-Vietoris long exact (consider the two hemispheres $H_\pm$ of $S^2$, and the subspaces $H_+\times K$ and $H_-\times K$)